# Absolute positioning relative to html tag

Tags: css, css-position

I am trying to absolutely position a html element that resides in the footer of a web page. I want it to be positioned next to items in the main menu.

Absolute positioning doesn't work because the height of the page keeps changing and the element I am trying to position gets positioned relative to its parent.

Is there a way to absolutely position an element relative to the html tag instead of the parent? Essentially I want to position like if the element was fixed so it always appears on the same place on the page, but it should be part of the document tree and scroll with the page.

**EDIT**
The element can't be moved so the positioning needs to be done though CSS entirely.

Comment: Why not make the element to be positioned a child of the menu since it will appear there anyway?

Comment: In this particular case the element can't be moved and therefore the positioning needs to be done entirely through CSS. Is that possible?

Comment: So you would have to show us the structure. Please post your HTML & CSS and a JSfiddle. A link to the actual page would also be useful if available.

Answer (score 0):

Make the element child of the menu and then it will appear relative to menu.Small example is given below

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
  <div id="elementDiv"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu
{
width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

#elementDiv
{
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    width:50px;
    height:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/35ccs/1/

Comment: This is a good answer. However, in this particular case the element can't be moved and therefore the positioning needs to be done entirely through CSS. Is it possible?

Comment: @Karl Yes position can be done. Using absolute and top left properties relative to the parent element

Comment: I meant I cannot move the element in html/change the html structure, I can only manipulate through CSS. AFAIK its not possible to change the parent using CSS.